# Wordpress plugin to insert CSS/JS into post

Tags: wordpress

I have searched the seven seas, and can not find the simple plugin I desire. I am sure I have seen it before - and seems so obviously useful.

As I remember it, there was a box on every post/page's editing page, where I could write some javascript or css, and it would be inserted into the head of that page only.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply here, but I think you are talking about the [Insert Javascript and CSS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-javascript-css/) pluggin